# Adding additional day in array to correct date format in angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays, date-format, isodate

In my angular project, I have a array like this:

```
Thali : [
  {"date":"2017-04-09T18:30:00.000Z","isHoliday":"100"},
  {"date":"2017-04-10T18:30:00.000Z","isHoliday":"101"}
]
```

from date picker I selected like first value `2017-04-10` (10 April) and in `IsoDate` format it shows 1 day less. so need to add 1 day in date but this is array. so how I can add 1 day in all dates of array or able to change format of `Isodate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using pure JavaScript

```js
var arr = [
  {"date":"2017-04-09T18:30:00.000Z","isHoliday":"100"},
  {"date":"2017-04-10T18:30:00.000Z","isHoliday":"101"}
]

arr.forEach(function(entry) {
 var d = new Date(entry["date"]);
 // Add one day
 d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    // Replace existing date in array with the new one
 entry["date"] = d.toISOString()
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use **moment.js** library. Link: https://momentjs.com/docs/
Example after integrating moment.js with your application:

```
var new_date = moment(your_date, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(1, 'day');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't just add/remove days from dates. Use library like https://momentjs.com/ to convert between UTC and local dates.

Answer (score 0):

It is not going a day less. It's just showing it in `GMT` timezone where as when you selected date from datePicker, it was in `IST (GMT +5:30)`

```js
var asd = new Date("2017-04-10 00:00:00")
console.log(asd.toISOString())
```